# How do I build and compare an Array against another array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, comparison, iteration

I have an `ArrayList` containing strings retrieved from a database. The strings are tags for individual posts of a blog, for example:

```
video, java, php, xml,

css, java, foo, bar, 

xml, php, foo, bar, dog
```

I am attempting to loop through the list. Split each string by their commas into an array and check if my uniqueTag array doesn't contain an element from the split array. If it doesn't, add it to the uniqueTag array.

This is how far I've got:

```
List<String> tagList = conn.getAllTags();
String[] uniqueTags;
for(String item: tagList){
    // split the row into array of comman seperated elements
    String[] splitItem = item.split(",");

    for(int i=-1; i<=splitItem.length; i++){
        // compare this element with elements in uniqueTags
        // and if it doesn't exit in uniqueTags
        // add it.
    }
}
```

How do I compare and dynamically build the uniqueTags array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `Set<String>` to prevent duplicate values.

Something along the lines of:

```
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>();
for(String item: tagList){
    // split the row into array of comman seperated elements
    String[] splitItem = item.split(",");
    for (String item: splitItem) {
        uniques.add(item.trim()); // trimming whitespace and adding to set

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you try something like this.

Create a `List<String>` splitIteams of split items and do

```
List<String> distinct = splitItems.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.printf("Split Items : %s,  Distinct list : %s ", splitItems, distinct);
```

Edit - deleted one extra %s

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void compareArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    boolean b = true;
    if (array1 != null && array2 != null){

      if (array1.length != array2.length)
          b = false;
      else
          for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
              if (array2[i] != array1[i]) {
                  b = false;    
              }                 
        }
    }else{
      b = false;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```